# Can video.js be used offline, on a CD/DVD/flash drive?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am creating an HTML-based video gallery that will be distributed on physical media and needs to be functional in the absence of an internet connection. I will store the video files in an assets folder inside the root folder.

Will video.js function in the absence of an internet connection, packaged as a stand-alone mini-site on physical media?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In the same way that you can reference images locally relative to an HTML page, you can do the same thing with video.

so if you file is index.html and assets are in a folder called video you would simply reference something like src="video/myvideo.mp4"